# Draw 4 of the same figure in the same tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this: [image]

I have managed to do one of the Hexagons using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=round,>=latex]

  \newdimen\R
  \R=0.8cm
\coordinate (center) at (0,0);
\draw (0:\R)
 \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) }
          -- cycle (300:\R) node[below] {}
          -- cycle (240:\R) node[below] {}
          -- cycle (180:\R) node[left] {}
          -- cycle (120:\R) node[above] {}
          -- cycle (60:\R) node[above] {}
          -- cycle (0:\R) node[right] {};
\draw { (60:\R) -- (30:0.69) -- (center) -- (60:\R) } [fill=gray];
\draw { (90:0.69) -- (120:\R) -- (center) -- (90:0.69) } [fill=gray];
\draw { (180:\R) -- (150:0.69) -- (center) -- (180:\R) } [fill=gray];
\draw { (240:\R) -- (210:0.69) -- (center) -- (240:\R) } [fill=gray];
\draw { (300:\R) -- (270:0.69) -- (center) -- (300:\R) } [fill=gray];
\draw { (0:\R) -- (330:0.69) -- (center) -- (0:\R) } [fill=gray];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And it draw this:

[image]

But when I try to do 4 of them, it is really complicated to me, please help with that. Thank you

Comment: the `\newdimen\R` should be in the preamble not inside an environment (newdimen allocations are always global) but then can you not simply copy the tikzpicture 4 times?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally the recommendation is to use `pic`s but here you can just use a slightly extended standard node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\tikzset{repeating shape/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,alias=curr,draw,append after command={
    [draw,] foreach \XX [remember=\XX as \YY (initially #1)] 
    in {1,...,#1} {
    (curr.corner \XX) -- (curr.center) -- ($(curr.corner \YY)!0.5!(curr.corner
    \XX)$)}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \draw[fill=gray] foreach \X in {0,2.2} { foreach \Y in {0,2.2}
  {(\X,\Y) node[repeating shape=6,minimum size=3cm]{} }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? Good job. Can you add comments indicating what each section of your code does in order for other readers to have an idea on how replicate or edit the sections.

Comment: @azetina No sorcery, only `append after command` which can be found on p. 150 of the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 4):

No one prevents you from `pic`, with as many options as possible.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newdimen\R
\R=0.8cm
\tikzset{
  pics/hexagon/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    code={
      \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=2*\R] (x) {};
      \coordinate (x.corner 0) at (x.corner 6);
      \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
        \fill[#1] (x.center) -- (x.{\i*60}) -- (x.{\i*60+30});
        \fill[#2] (x.center) -- (x.{\i*60-30}) -- (x.{\i*60});
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (-1,-1) {hexagon=gray and black};
\pic at (-1, 1) {hexagon=gray and black};
\pic at ( 1,-1) {hexagon=gray and black};
\pic at ( 1, 1) {hexagon=gray and black};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2}
\def\subpic{
\fill[gray] (0:\a)--(60:\a)--(120:\a)
--(180:\a)--(240:\a)--(300:\a)--cycle;
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5} 
\fill[rotate=60*\i] (0,0)--(120:\a)-|cycle;
}

\foreach \j in {45,135,-135,-45}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(\j:4)}]
\subpic 
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ti*k*Z has special syntaxes for pics based on `pgfkeys`. There is no need to use `scope` and define a new command