# How can I make a line end at the edge of an irregular shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

I created an irregular shape (below the `Service` rectangle) using the `\draw` command. As part of a diagram I like to have an arrow point to the shape as seen below. The arrow currently ends a bit above the shape which is undesired.

[image: Diagram]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc, arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\device}[2]{
\node(#1) [draw,rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,rounded corners=0.2cm,#2] {};
\draw ($(#1) + (-0.25,0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (-0.25,0.75)$);
\draw ($(#1) + (0.25,0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (0.25,0.75)$);

\draw ($(#1) + (-0.25,-0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (-0.25,-0.75)$);
\draw ($(#1) + (0.25,-0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (0.25,-0.75)$);

\node [right=0.25cm of #1] {Device};
}

\newsavebox{\persistence}
\savebox{\persistence}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=white] ($(0,0)$) to ($(0,0) + (0,1)$) to [out=90,in=90] ($(0,0) + (1,1)$) to ($(0,0) + (1,0)$) to [out=-90,in=-90] ($(0,0) + (0,0)$);
\draw (0,1) to [out=-90,in=-90] ($(0,0) + (1,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{arr}=[-{Latex[length=2mm]}];

\node(machine) [draw, rectangle] {Machine};
\device{adevice}{right=3cm of machine}

\draw [->, arr] (machine.east) -- node[above] {Data} (adevice.west);
\node(broker) [draw, rectangle, below=1.5cm of adevice, align=center] {Broker};
\draw [->, arr] (adevice.south) -- node[right, align=left] {Data} (broker.north);

\node(dts) [draw, rectangle, align=center, right=5cm of broker] {Service};

\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=2mm]broker.east) to [bend left=15] node[above] {Data} ([yshift=2mm]dts.west);
\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=-2mm]dts.west) to [bend left=15] node[above=1mm] {Data} ([yshift=-2mm]broker.east);

\node(persistence) [below=of dts] {\usebox{\persistence}};

\draw [->, arr] (dts.south) to (persistence) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Image} \label{fig:Deployment concept}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is the side effect when you nest Ti*k*Z picture. Never nest Ti*k*Z pictures.

Comment: Is there any other solution? Especially when I like to reuse a shape.

Comment: See Ignasi's answer. Btw why do you use `($(0,0)$)` or `($(0,0) + (0,1)$)`? Aren't `(0,0)` and `(0,1)` ok?

Comment: That was a relic from some time before where it was calculated. It was just a quick replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a new node shape is not that easy. Looking at how Ti*k*Z/PGF defines shape `ellipse` in [`pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex) for example:

```
% pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex, lines 12-194
\pgfdeclareshape{ellipse}
%
% Draws a circle around the text
%
{%
  \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }%
  \savedanchor\radius{%
    %
    % Calculate ``height radius''
    %
    \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
    %
    % Calculate ``width radius''
    %
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
    %
    % Adjust
    %
    \pgf@x=1.4142136\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=1.4142136\pgf@y%
    %
    % Adjust height, if necessary
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@y<.5\pgf@yc%
      \pgf@y=.5\pgf@yc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Adjust width, if necessary
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xc%
      \pgf@x=.5\pgf@xc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Add outer sep
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
  }%

  %
  % Anchors
  %
  \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
  \anchor{mid}{\centerpoint\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}}%
  \anchor{base}{\centerpoint\pgf@y=0pt}%
  \anchor{north}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{south}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{west}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa
  }%
  \anchor{mid west}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}
  }%
  \anchor{base west}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
    \pgf@y=0pt
  }%
  \anchor{north west}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{south west}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by-0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{east}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa
  }%
  \anchor{mid east}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}
  }%
  \anchor{base east}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
    \pgf@y=0pt
  }%
  \anchor{north east}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{south east}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by-0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchorborder{
    \edef\pgf@marshal{%
      \noexpand\pgfpointborderellipse
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}
      {\noexpand\radius}%
    }%
    \pgf@marshal%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \centerpoint%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
  }%

  %
  % Background path
  %
  \backgroundpath
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgf@x%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgf@y%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by-\pgf@yb%
    \pgfpathellipse{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
  }%
}%
```

Node shape needs to be defined using PGF commands, because there are no Ti*k*Z syntaxes for this.

So, avoid defining a new node shape. There are already *many* in `shapes` libraries.

However, if you already have a code, and you want to place it many times inside Ti*k*Z pictures, you can use `pic`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
\newcommand{\device}[2]{
    \node(#1) [draw,rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,rounded corners=0.2cm,#2] {};
    \draw ($(#1) + (-0.25,0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (-0.25,0.75)$);
    \draw ($(#1) + (0.25,0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (0.25,0.75)$);
    \draw ($(#1) + (-0.25,-0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (-0.25,-0.75)$);
    \draw ($(#1) + (0.25,-0.25)$) -- ($(#1) + (0.25,-0.75)$);
    \node [right=0.25cm of #1] {Device};
}
\tikzset{
    arr/.style={-{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    persistence/.pic={
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,-.5)}]
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0) to (0,1) to [out=90,in=90] (1,1) to (1,0) to [out=-90,in=-90] (0,0);
        \draw (0,1) to [out=-90,in=-90] (1,1);
        % Here I make four "anchors". Define more if you need to, delete if you don't need
        \path[postaction=decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with \coordinate (#1-north);
        }] (0,1) to [out=90,in=90] (1,1);
        \path[postaction=decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with \coordinate (#1-south);
        }] (0,0) to [out=-90,in=-90] (1,0);
        \path[postaction=decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with \coordinate (#1-west);
        }] (0,1) -- (0,0);
        \path[postaction=decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with \coordinate (#1-east);
        }] (1,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(machine) [draw, rectangle] {Machine};
\device{adevice}{right=3cm of machine}
\draw [->, arr] (machine.east) -- node[above] {Data} (adevice.west);
\node(broker) [draw, rectangle, below=1.5cm of adevice, align=center] {Broker};
\draw [->, arr] (adevice.south) -- node[right, align=left] {Data} (broker.north);
\node(dts) [draw, rectangle, align=center, right=5cm of broker] {Service};
\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=2mm]broker.east) to [bend left=15] node[above] {Data} ([yshift=2mm]dts.west);
\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=-2mm]dts.west) to [bend left=15] node[above=1mm] {Data} ([yshift=-2mm]broker.east);
\pic[below=of dts,yshift=-1cm] {persistence=pers}; 
\draw [->, arr] (dts.south) to (pers-north); % NOT pers.north
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that even when the code is a much simpler one, it is still overcomplicated. Therefore, my suggestion, in conclusion, is: you should have a look at `shapes` libraries. There are already many things to choose from. Only defining a new shape if it is blatantly different from available ones, and can't be drawn using a (collection of) modified version(s) of available one(s).

Comment: why defined new shape, if already exist `cylinder` shape? well, apparently  op admire complex solution :-)

Comment: @Zarko I define a new shape (well actually it is a `pic`) because the OP wants. I don't want :))

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `cylinder` shape for this node. And a `rectangle` node with some added lines for the `device` shape. This way you won't have to nest `tikzpictures`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.misc, positioning, calc, arrows.meta}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    arr/.style={-{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    persistence/.style={cylinder, shape border rotate=90, 
        minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=1cm, draw},
    device/.style={minimum size=1cm, rounded corners=.2cm, alias=current,
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
            \draw ([shift={(.25,-.25)}]current.north west)--++(90:.5);
            \draw ([shift={(-.25,-.25)}]current.north east)--++(90:.5);
            \draw ([shift={(.25,-.25)}]current.south west)--++(90:.5);
            \draw ([shift={(-.25,-.25)}]current.south east)--++(90:.5);
            \endpgfextra
        }
    }
    ]

\node(machine) [draw, rectangle] {Machine};
\node[device, right=3cm of machine, draw] (dev) {};

\draw [->, arr] (machine.east) -- node[above] {Data} (dev.west);
\node(broker) [draw, rectangle, below=1.5cm of dev, align=center] {Broker};
\draw [->, arr] (dev.south) -- node[right, align=left] {Data} (broker.north);

\node(dts) [draw, rectangle, align=center, right=5cm of broker] {Service};

\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=2mm]broker.east) to [bend left=15] node[above] {Data} ([yshift=2mm]dts.west);
\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=-2mm]dts.west) to [bend left=15] node[above=1mm] {Data} ([yshift=-2mm]broker.east);

\node[persistence, below=of dts] (per) {};

\draw [->, arr] (dts.south) to (per.top);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Image} \label{fig:Deployment concept}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some way to do this for any type of shape?

Comment: @Daniel No. TikZ have some defined `shapes` that you can look at shapes library section in pgfmanual. If your desired shape is not there, you can use `pics` which are like tiny pictures which can be reused. An example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151772/1952

Comment: @Daniel By the way I've also replaced your `device` with a regular node and some `append after command` lines.

Comment: @Daniel Read `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex` to see how complicated it is to define a new shape.

Answer (score 1):

as supplement to @ignasy answer, with use of the `calc` and `quotes` TikZ libraries and a little bit changed picture elements styles:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
              auto = left,
     node distance = 11mm and 28mm,
        arr/.style = {-{Latex[length=2mm]}},
        box/.style = {draw, minimum height=6mm, outer sep=0pt},
     device/.style = {minimum size=1cm, rounded corners=.2cm, alias=current,
        append after command={\pgfextra{
        \draw ([sxy=-2]current.north) -- ++ (0, .4)
              ([sxy= 2]current.north) -- ++ (0,-.4)
              ([sxy=-2]current.south) -- ++ (0, .4)
              ([sxy= 2]current.south) -- ++ (0,-.4);}},
                     draw},
persistence/.style = {cylinder, draw, shape border rotate=90,
                      minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm},
       sxy/.style = {xshift=#1mm,yshift=#1mm}
                    ]

\node (machine) [box] {Machine};
\node (dev)     [device, label=right:Device,
                 right=of machine]  {};
\draw [arr] (machine) to ["Data"]   (dev);
%
\node (broker)  [box, below=of dev] {Broker};
\draw[arr]  (dev)     to ["Data"]   (broker);
%
\node (dts) [box, right=of broker]  {Service};
\draw[arr]  (broker.10) edge [bend left, "Data"] (dts.170)
            (dts.190)    to  [bend left, "Data"] (broker.350);
%
\node (per) [persistence, below=of dts] {};
\draw[arr]  (dts) to ($(per.after top)!0.5!(per.before top)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Image}
    \label{fig:Deployment concept}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an addendum to [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487344/121799) but with an arguably better (or correct) usage of `append after command` from [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485644/121799), i.e. without `\pgfextra`, about which the pgfmanual says on p. 166

> Note that this operation should only be used by real experts and
>   should only be used deep inside clever macros, not on normal paths.

There are many things that can go wrong if one uses `\pgfextra` on a path, which prompted me to post this addendum. And one doesn't need it here (nor in any other cases I have seen). The only thing that one has to do to make `append after command` is to replace `\node`, which is a shortcut for `\path node`, with `\draw node`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.misc, positioning, calc, arrows.meta}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    arr/.style={-{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    persistence/.style={cylinder, shape border rotate=90, 
        minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=1cm, draw},
    device/.style={minimum size=1cm, rounded corners=.2cm, alias=current,
        append after command={
            ([shift={(.25,-.25)}]current.north west)--++(90:.5)
            ([shift={(-.25,-.25)}]current.north east)--++(90:.5)
            ([shift={(.25,-.25)}]current.south west)--++(90:.5)
            ([shift={(-.25,-.25)}]current.south east)--++(90:.5)
        }
    }
    ]

\node(machine) [draw, rectangle] {Machine};
\draw node[device, right=3cm of machine, draw] (dev) {};

\draw [->, arr] (machine.east) -- node[above] {Data} (dev.west);
\node(broker) [draw, rectangle, below=1.5cm of dev, align=center] {Broker};
\draw [->, arr] (dev.south) -- node[right, align=left] {Data} (broker.north);

\node(dts) [draw, rectangle, align=center, right=5cm of broker] {Service};

\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=2mm]broker.east) to [bend left=15] node[above] {Data} ([yshift=2mm]dts.west);
\draw [->, arr] ([yshift=-2mm]dts.west) to [bend left=15] node[above=1mm] {Data} ([yshift=-2mm]broker.east);

\node[persistence, below=of dts] (per) {};

\draw [->, arr] (dts.south) to (per.top);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Image} \label{fig:Deployment concept}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good to know! Is there a way to create a `circle` on a the layer `foreground` within `append after command` without using `\pgfextra`? Up to now I used `\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground} \node[circle, fill=white, minimum size=5mm, draw] at (current.north) {}; \end{pgfonlayer}` within `\pgfextra`.

Comment: @Daniel Where do you want to create the circle? And no, AFAIK you cannot switch the layers in `append after command` but there are of course `pic`s with which you can.

Comment: This is the entire command within the options of `tikzpicture`: `consumer/.style={xscale=0.5, semicircle, minimum height=10mm, draw, alias=current, append after command={
\pgfextra{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\node[circle, fill=white, minimum size=5mm, draw] at (current.north) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
}}`.

Comment: @Daniel How about you ask a new question with complete example on this? Your original question has already enough answers, I think, and asking questions is free.